# How to make chart in excel combine values with same name

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office

[image]

I want to sum up all "chick-01","duck-02" and shows in one bar instead multiple bar with same name.

I tried using SUMIF command to total up the same name, but it is possible to directly combine **without** using SUMIF and any additional command? I tried to not use additional command as my current excel sheet will be added more model and it already large.

Thank you.

Comment: Then calculate that sum on the sheet and chart that data....

Comment: yes i done that, but i just asking if there any possible solution without using any command and automatically chart the same name.

Comment: if you want to swap between data on the chart you can use choose() and a cell with data validation  to select which item.